# System tray tooltips in Tauri

Tags: rust, tauri

Is there a simple way to make a tooltip appear when hovering a system tray icon? This is really common in Windows apps. [SystemTrayEvent](https://docs.rs/tauri/1.2.4/tauri/enum.SystemTrayEvent.html) does not appear to support a hover event, and [SystemTray](https://docs.rs/tauri/1.0.0-beta.8/tauri/struct.SystemTray.html) does not seem to have a way to set a hover text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search tooltip on docs.rs you can find [one](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/struct.SystemTray.html#method.with_tooltip)

Example:

```rust
let tray = SystemTray::new().with_menu(tray_menu).with_tooltip("App Name");
```

Comment: Aha! This appears to be a new-ish feature. One caveat though: it's unsupported on Linux. Regardless, thanks for pointing it out!